# MVC 2 Redirecting to Login page after POST, How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a basic controller with a create action with both a GET and a POST. The GET works fine and renders the page, however, the POST always redirects me back to the login page and my data does not save. I am using forms authentication but I'm not using the [Authorize] attribute yet on any of my controller actions. Everything works fine locally on my machine, but when I publish to the server, this error starts happening. Here is the code for my create methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var employee = new EmployeeViewModel();
        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var dataModel = viewModel.TransformToDataModel();
        allEmployees.Add(dataModel);
        ViewData["SuccessMessage"] = string.Format("{0} successfully added to the system", viewModel.Name);
        return View("Success");
    }
```

I am using the default AspNetSql Membership/RoleProvider/ProfileProvider and am hosting on GoDaddy using IIS 7.0. Here are the main parts of my web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms 
        name="formCookie" protection="None" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" requireSSL="false"
       loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" path="/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

If anyone has come across this error before or knows what is going on, this would be of immense help. Thank you!

Comment: Is the [Authorize] Attribute on the controller itself? If it is then that will cascade through all the actions in the controller.

Comment: `return View("Success");` do you have a View named "Success" ?

Comment: That would just generate an error though wouldn't it, Unless in <CustomErrors> the default url for the error was the login page?

Comment: I haven't used any [Authorize] attributes yet. I wanted to see if I can get it to work before I user the [Authorize(Roles="Manager")].

Comment: Yes, there is a view named "Success", it's basically a pass through that sets a success message.

Comment: So, chalk it up to being a noob. When working with GoDaddy, you can edit permissions to a directory to inhert, read, and/or write. I did this and removed the 

    <identity impersonate="true" />

from the web.config and magically everything worked. I am using an XML file to store information and wasn't seeing an error because I didn't specify an error page.

Thanks to all that helped. Hopefully this can help other developers that are struggling with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC the preferred way to handle authorization is by using the `[Authorize]` attribute. The `<authorization>` section in web.config should be removed.